# How do I split sentence in java by word(with parenthesis)?

Tags: java, parsing, split

For instance, this works:

```
String test = "I am a good boy";
String splitbyWord = "a good";
System.out.println(test.split(splitbyWord)[1]); => boy
```

But this does not:

```
String test = "I am a (good) boy";
String splitbyWord = "a (good)";
System.out.println(test.split(splitbyWord)[1]);

=>index out of bound
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `split()` takes a regular expression, and parentheses have a special meaning in regular expressions. The general solution to this is to use [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
        System.out.println(test.split(Pattern.quote(splitbyWord))[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

[String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses a regular expression. Round parenthesis are special characters used to denote the bounds of  [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html). They should be escaped:

```
String splitbyWord = "a \\(good\\)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the split method in javadoc. It uses regular expressions to split the string. I think that parenthesis mark a group in regex so you should escape them:

```
String splitbyWord = "a \\(good\\)";
```

Comment: They do indeed indicate a capturing group.  This answer is very similar to an existing one by NPE however.

Comment: Indeed, I was too slow while writing it